# increase / decrease opacity using mousemove event

Tags: javascript, css

I have this slider and I want to decrease the opacity and hide .banner div if the slider is sliding left and increase the opacity of .banner div and make the banner div appear again if the slider is sliding right.

My current code can only decrease the opacity but cannot increase it, how can i fix this?

CodePen Link: https://codepen.io/mjkno1/pen/zYWPjEw

```js
let sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
let innerSlider = document.querySelector(".inner-slider");
let banner = document.querySelector(".banner");

let pressed = false;
let startX;
let x;
let bannerOpacity = banner.style.opacity
let oldx = 0

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
  startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

// sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
//     sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
// });

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "default";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
  pressed = false;
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  // pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!pressed) return;

  console.log(e.pageX);
  if (e.pageX > oldx && banner.style.opacity === 0) {
    banner.style.opacity += 0.01
    console.log('right');
  } else if (e.pageX < oldx) {
    console.log('left');
    banner.style.opacity -= 0.01
  }
  e.preventDefault();

  x = e.offsetX;

  innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
  oldx = e.pageX;
  checkBoundary();
});

const checkBoundary = () => {
  let outer = sliderContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
  let inner = innerSlider.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (parseInt(innerSlider.style.left) > 150) {
    innerSlider.style.left -= 10;
    // bannerOpacity -= 0.01
  }

  if (inner.right < outer.right) {
    innerSlider.style.left = `-${inner.width - outer.width}px`;
  }
};
```

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.banner {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}


/* .card:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
} */

.card:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
}

.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-slider {
  width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="banner" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
    <div class="inner-slider">
      <!-- <div class="card"></div> -->
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you want the div to only increase its opacity after it disappeared?

Comment: I guess you are re-inveting the wheel. if you search you will find libraries for your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`banner.style.opacity` has `typeof` being string.

So, especially when adding a number literal to its value, the type coercion doesn't kick in on our favor. To make the conversion explicit, we should first parse the string as a float number before adding the `0.01` amount.

This is that part refactored (only on the addition):

```
if (e.pageX > oldx && banner.style.opacity < 1) {
  banner.style.opacity = parseFloat(banner.style.opacity) + 0.01;
} else if (e.pageX < oldx && banner.style.opacity > 0) {
  banner.style.opacity -= 0.01
}
```

And this is the whole demo having the new logic and showing how the opacity gets triggered both when sliding to the left and to the right:

```js
let sliderContainer = document.querySelector(".slider-container");
let innerSlider = document.querySelector(".inner-slider");
let banner = document.querySelector(".banner");

let pressed = false;
let startX;
let x;
let bannerOpacity = banner.style.opacity
let oldx = 0

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
  pressed = true;
  startX = e.offsetX - innerSlider.offsetLeft;
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grabbing";
});

// sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseenter", () => {
//     sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
// });

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "default";
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  sliderContainer.style.cursor = "grab";
  pressed = false;
});

window.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
  // pressed = false;
});

sliderContainer.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  if (!pressed) return;

  console.log(`e.pageX:${e.pageX};oldx:${oldx};op:${banner.style.opacity}`);
  console.log(banner.style.opacity + 1);
  if (e.pageX > oldx && banner.style.opacity < 1) {
    banner.style.opacity = parseFloat(banner.style.opacity) + 0.01;
    console.log('right');
  } else if (e.pageX < oldx && banner.style.opacity > 0) {
    console.log('left');
    banner.style.opacity -= 0.01
  }
  e.preventDefault();

  x = e.offsetX;

  innerSlider.style.left = `${x - startX}px`;
  oldx = e.pageX;
  checkBoundary();
});

const checkBoundary = () => {
  let outer = sliderContainer.getBoundingClientRect();
  let inner = innerSlider.getBoundingClientRect();

  if (parseInt(innerSlider.style.left) > 150) {
    innerSlider.style.left -= 10;
    // bannerOpacity -= 0.01
  }

  if (inner.right < outer.right) {
    innerSlider.style.left = `-${inner.width - outer.width}px`;
  }
};
```

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.banner {
  z-index: 2;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}

.card:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}


/* .card:first-child {
    visibility: hidden;
} */

.card:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: rgb(0, 183, 255);
}

.slider-container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner-slider {
  width: 150%;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="banner" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
    <div class="inner-slider">
      <!-- <div class="card"></div> -->
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! didn't realize banner.style.opacity is a string